# query data in four levels tables by laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I have this SQL structure to query schools and the number of student of male gender,
I am asking for help for converting it to laravel eloquent

```
SELECT *
FROM schools && count(students has(gender == 'male'))
JOIN grades ON (grades.schools = schools.school_id)
JOIN streams ON (stream.schools = schools.school_id)
JOIN students ON (student.schools = schools.school_id)
```

this is what i did in the schemas
school schema

```
 Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('educationLevel');
            $table->foreignId('ward_id')
            ->constrained('wards')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

grade

```
Schema::create('grades', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->foreignId('school_id')->constrained('schools')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();});
```

stream

```
 Schema::create('streams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignId('grade_id')
            ->constrained('grades')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
```

student

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
            $table->string('student_name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->foreignId('stream_id')
            ->constrained('streams')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

this is what i tried before
in school controller

```
$schools = School::select(['name'])->withCount('students')->where('students', function($query){
    $query->where('gender', 'male');
})
->get();
```

in school model i did this below

```
 public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Grade::class);
    }

  
    public function students(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Student::class, Stream::class, Grade::class);
    }
```

the relationship of this models is one to many like below
school->has->grade->has->stream->student(gender = male or female)

Comment: Can you post the table structure for all tables?

Comment: I have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage **addSelect** to get the desired output

```php
School::query()
  ->addSelect([
      /** Total no of students in school */
      'count_students' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
          ->whereIn(
            'stream_id', 
            Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
              'grade_id',
              Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
            )
          ),
      /** Total no of "gender = male" students in school */
      'count_male' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
          ->whereRaw('gender = "male"')
          ->whereIn(
            'stream_id', 
            Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
              'grade_id',
              Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
            )
          ),
      /** Total no of "gender = female" students in school */
      'count_female' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
          ->whereRaw('gender = "female"')
          ->whereIn(
            'stream_id', 
            Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
              'grade_id',
              Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
            )
          ),
      /** Total no of "gender = other" students in school */
      'count_other' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
          ->whereRaw('gender = "other"')
          ->whereIn(
            'stream_id', 
            Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
              'grade_id',
              Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
            )
          )
  ])->get();
```

Comment: I love this approach, I have learned a lot from this thanks for the solution,

Answer (score 0):

You would need something approaching this:

```
$schools  = School::Join('grades', 'grades.schools', '=', 'schools.school_id')
            ->Join('stream', 'stream.schools', '=', 'schools.school_id')
            ->Join('student', 'student.schools', '=', 'schools.school_id')
            ->where('gender', "male")
            ->get([
                'name','yourdata'
            ]);
```

To get the count of data, you simply calculate with count method.

```
$schoolCount = count($schools);
```

Make sure your table and column names are appropriate, I am seeing a lot of inconsistencies in your model and table names, same for columns. also, using join you might run into issues like columns with same name. make sure to specify them separately in the get method.Like:

```
->get([
                'id', 'student.schools as stud', 'stream.name as streamName', 
            ]);
```